# Fill every minute in an interval of timestamps with a static record in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a time series in MySQL and need to write a cycle as described by the pseudocode below:

```
FOR DATETIME BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2 WITH STEP OF 1 MIN
     INSERT INTO TABLE X ('TIMESTAMP', 'COLUMN1', 'COLUMN2') VALUES (DATETIME, NULL, NULL);
ENDFOR
```

how do I write this, optimally, in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using a recursive CTE for a 1 minute interval is that you very quickly hit the default max recursion depth (1000) because a day has 1440 minutes, resulting in the error:

> `Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value

To overcome this restriction without changing the recursion depth and to insert rows for longer durations I used a loop in a function.

```
CREATE TABLE lookup_time_instance(time_instance DATETIME PRIMARY KEY);

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDatetimeValues()
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentDate DATETIME;
    SET currentDate = '2023-01-01'

    -- Change the end date as required, this is for 1 month
    WHILE currentDate < '2023-02-01' DO
        INSERT INTO lookup_time_instance (time_instance) VALUES (currentDate);
        SET currentDate = DATE_ADD(currentDate, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);
    END WHILE;
END //

DELIMITER ;

-- Call the stored procedure to insert the datetime values
CALL InsertDatetimeValues();
```

It's not fast but as I'm creating a lookup table to use in queries it is only run once to build the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
insert into x (timestamp, column1, column2)
    with recursive cte as (
          select @date1 as dte
          union all
          select dte + interval 1 minute
          from cte
          where dte < @date2
         )
     select dt, null, null
     from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8a2eecee3a1bca89d7322435a5e5ffc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: except it would be 1 minute for my case :)